# Excluding specific records using LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
StudentID   Session   Semester   Subject

1           2012      1          1
1           2012      1          2
1           2012      1          3
1           2012      1          4
1           2012      1          5
1           2012      2          6
1           2012      2          7
1           2012      2          8
1           2012      2          9
1           2012      2          10
1           2013      2          1
1           2013      2          13
1           2013      2          14
1           2013      2          15
1           2013      2          16
1           2013      3          17
1           2013      3          18
1           2013      3          19
1           2013      3          20
1           2013      3          21
```

I don't know what can i name the query which I want to generate. I searched a lot but couldn't find any result. 
What I want to do is to write a query which will help me to select the records of semester 1,2 and 3 but want to exclude the records which are the same semester of different session. To specifically say (I want to retrieve semester one of 2012 and 2 and 3 of 2013).

This action is repeated with unspecified session and semester.

Comment: Could you write data that you want to retrieve, like above table? I mean could you write result data table?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I want to select the semester 1 of 2012 plus semester 2 and 3 of 2013

Comment: @AqilAzad: why do you want to do this? Given the table it does not make any sense as to why you would need to do this. Is the *user* telling you which years/semesters they want? Or is this just a simple case of "I'd like to have the results of this query?"

Comment: If I have understood the query correctly, I think Aqil wants to select the minimum session for each semester. Admittedly, such a query would make sense for courses where there were multiple occurrences for the course and we wanted to select the earliest one.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I actullay want to generate the transcript for the students of an institute. they might have failed in a specific semester of a specific session. They will definitely join the next session and will get the result for the same semester in new session. What i want is that I don't want to miss the previous results. I want to only select the new semester plus previous semesters which are not repeated in other sessions. I think that make sense for my client.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out what that query is meant to represent, but you certainly can use LINQ to achieve that result.

`Where` will help you par down the results and `SelectMany` will help you join multiple sequences.

```
var studentData = ...; // your table of data

var studentId = ...; // student Id

var requestedRecords = new [] 
    {
        new { Session = 2012, Semester = 1 },
        new { Session = 2013, Semester = 2 },
        new { Session = 2013, Semester = 3 },
    };

var query = requestedRecords.SelectMany(
                rr => studentData.Where(
                          ss => ss.StudentID == studentId
                             && ss.Session == rr.Session 
                             && ss.Semester == rr.Semester)
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in Linqpad:

```
var tuples = new[] {
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 1, 1),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 1, 2),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 1, 3),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 1, 4),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 1, 5),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 2, 6),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 2, 7),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 2, 8),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 2, 9),
Tuple.Create(1, 2012, 2, 10),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 2, 1),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 2, 13),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 2, 14),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 2, 15),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 2, 16),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 3, 17),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 3, 18),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 3, 19),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 3, 20),
Tuple.Create(1, 2013, 3, 21)};
tuples
    .GroupBy(t => t.Item3)
    .Select (g => g.Where(x => x.Item2 == g.Max (x1 => x1.Item2)))
    .Dump();
```

So you get the semesters in the highest year you find for a semester.

Output:

```
Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 
1 2012 1 1 
1 2012 1 2 
1 2012 1 3 
1 2012 1 4 
1 2012 1 5 

Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 
1 2013 2 1 
1 2013 2 13 
1 2013 2 14 
1 2013 2 15 
1 2013 2 16 

Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 
1 2013 3 17 
1 2013 3 18 
1 2013 3 19 
1 2013 3 20 
1 2013 3 21
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a self-join here. You will want to first do a group-by and get the min(session) for each session/semester combination, then you want to join this result with the full table again joining on session and semester.

Here's [a very good resource for LINQ samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b/viewsamplepack). I do not have my [LINQpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to hand, otherwise I would have knocked something up for you.

I normally steer clear from recommending products, but LINQPad is a think of beauty when it comes to prototyping LINQ queries or even C# snippets.

The SQL will look something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Course AS C
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(IC.Session),
            IC.Semester
        FROM
            Course AS IC
        GROUP BY
            IC.Session,
            IC.Semester
    ) AS Q ON C.Session = Q.Session AND C.Semester = Q.Semester
```

Comment: I think I did what you say. You may please write your query even if SQL

Comment: unfortunately the result is different

Comment: Try MAX rather than MIN. I think that should sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

**LINQ 'Except' method**

I think you might be interested in the [LINQ 'Except' method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but i couldn't found a query to select the excludes for except. I mean I couldn't query the semester 2 of 2012

Comment: Except would work if what needs to be excluded was known in advance. I don't think that would work here.